# Why Strings are not equal in my case?

Tags: swift, string, number-formatting

I have `currencyFormatter` that is with `se_SV` locale.

```
var currencyFormatter: NumberFormatter = {
    let formatter = NumberFormatter()
    formatter.currencySymbol = ""
    formatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "se_SV")
    formatter.minimumFractionDigits = 2
    formatter.maximumFractionDigits = 2
    formatter.numberStyle = .currencyAccounting
    formatter.isLenient = true
    return formatter
}()
```

I am converting `NSNumber` to `String`.

```
let firstString = currencyFormatter.string(from: NSNumber(value: 22222222.50)) // "22 222 222,50 "
```

And than I create `String` manually that is same as `firstString`.

```
let secondString = "22 222 222,50 "
```

Why when I check if `firstString == secondString` I receive `false`?

Comment: They both have " " after ,50

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
print(Array(firstString!.unicodeScalars))
// ["2", "2", "\u{00A0}", "2", "2", "2", "\u{00A0}", "2", "2", "2", ",", "5", "0", "\u{00A0}"]

print(firstString!.replacingOccurrences(of: "\u{A0}", with: " ") == secondString)
// true
```

reveals that the number formatter separates the groups with "non-breaking spaces" `U+00A0`. This prevents the number from being split across
lines in a multi-line text.

Comment: makes sense as this will i.e. allow the accessibility interface to understand it as the correct numeric value rather several values.

Comment: You can see this by inspecting the formatter's `groupingSeparator` directly: `print(currencyFormatter.groupingSeparator.unicodeScalars.map { $0.escaped(asASCII: true) })` produces `["\\u{00A0}"]`