# NumberFormatter whitespace character is not a space - tests fail because of this

Tags: swift, formatting, locale, nsnumberformatter

I was writing some tests for some help functions for our currency handling code, and specifically the formatting of the different currency formats for the locales that relates to us.

This is a minimum example to replicate the same behaviour:

```
let positiveCurrencyValue = Decimal(string: "250.00")!
let negativeCurrencyValue = Decimal(string: "-250.00")!

let formatter = NumberFormatter()
formatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "nb_NO")
formatter.numberStyle = .currency
formatter.minimumFractionDigits = 2
formatter.maximumFractionDigits = 2

let positiveString = formatter.string(from: positiveCurrencyValue as NSNumber)!

if positiveString == "kr 250,00" {
    print("Positives are equal")
} else {
    print("Positives are NOT equal! \"\(positiveString)\" != \"kr 250,00\"")
}

formatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "sv_SE")

let negativeString = formatter.string(from: negativeCurrencyValue as NSNumber)!

if negativeString == "-250,00 kr" {
    print("Negatives are equal!")
} else {
    print("Negatives are NOT equal! \"\(negativeString)\" != \"kr -250,00\"")
}
```

In these two examples we're using a norwegian and a swedish locale. Neither of the strings we get match the strings expected, as the strings expected were originally written in a unit test. So this is what we'd expect.

The problem is that the whitespace is not an actual space. When I check the HEX values of the string returned by the formatter, I get the following (from [hexed.it](https://hexed.it/), LittleEndian):

```
"-250,00 kr" in hex (SEK):
\x{E28892}250,00\x{C2A0}kr
```

Even the "-" is messed up here.
Adding this line of code to the playground fixes that though: `formatter.negativePrefix = "-"`.

I cannot figure out how to fix the whitespace though. Is this issue caused by some string encoding settings? Given the HEX string up above, I assume it's not using UTF8 at all, but that's just my guess. I have tried to convert the string to data and back, using different encodings for the data step, but it did not do anything.

Comment: U+00A0  is a “non-breaking space”, compare https://stackoverflow.com/q/48795085.

Comment: @MartinR Okay, makes sense to have it this way, but we need to print on paper and this character breaks things. How do I override this? Setting `formatter.groupingSeparator = " "` did not work.

Comment: If necessary you can replace it with a “normal” space character, as shown in https://stackoverflow.com/a/48795185.

Comment: What @MartinR is telling you is to replace the normal space with a non-breaking space `if positiveString == "kr\u{00A0}250,00"` or the the other way by replacing the non-breaking space in `positiveString` with a normal space

Comment: @Carpsen90 I understand that, but the way to go about it if you wanted a normal space is not very intuitive. But I guess there's not much else to do

Comment: Is this `let positiveString = formatter.string(from: positiveCurrencyValue as NSNumber)!; let positiveStringCleaned = positiveString.replacingOccurrences(of: "\u{00A0}", with: " "); if positiveStringCleaned == "kr 250,00" {..` not so intuitive?

Comment: @Carpsen90 That setting `currencyGroupingSeparators` does not seem to do anything, so what does it mean to set it? There is this extra expace between the currency and the value that I do not know how to set. The answer in the other question suggests replacing it afterward. For the value `-250000.00`, parsed with `sv_SE` I get these scalars: `["-", "2", "5", "0", " ", "0", "0", "0", ",", "0", "0", "\\u{00A0}", "k", "r"]` when I set `currencyGroupingSeparator = " "`. So there is still this dangling space at the end.

Comment: Well, it did something, so my wording there was incorrect. I still want to know why I can't change that one within the formatter. That's the point of a formatter, to format, no? :) So if I have to do extra steps outside, then I'll have to wrap it to be able to customise that myself. Sure, I can do it. But I want to exhaust my options first because I don't feel satisfied with that, @Carpsen90

Comment: @Simon The `currencyGroupingSeparators` separates the thousands and millions, etc. You could try it with a visible character to see its effect

Comment: @Carpsen90 I know that. See above comment.